# Как установить линукс вместо диска C

Tags: linux

Винда у меня на диске C, а на D данные, можно ли как-то снести винду с C и установит ь Linux, чтобы не трогать D.

Comment: Судя по вопросу Вам лучше всего обратиться к специалисту. Либо погуглить эту тему и потренироваться на виртуальках.

Comment: Вас интересует можно ли это сделать? Если так, то да. Это можно, но не с кривыми руками.

Comment: Какой примерный алгоритм действий? Чтобы я мог почитать, разобраться.